# How can I correctly set routes of a new Bundle in an existing Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml, symfony-2.8

I am working on a Symfony project, where the other developers are not really giving project-specific information, so this work is one of the worst project experience for me in the last five years. I am to create two Symfony bundles, an `OrderBundle` and an `ErpBundle`, to create some entities in the `OrderBundle` along with a service and a controller into `ErpBundle`.

The entities are normal Doctrine entities, I do not think they are important from this question's point of view. The `HomeController` is in the folder of

mainfolder/vendor/Myproject/myfolder/src/Myproject/App/ErpBundle/Controller/Admin/HomeController.php and it is like this:

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\App\ErpBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", defaults={
     *     "_format": "html"
     * })
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //some code
    }

    /**
     * @Route(  "/home/menu",
     *          defaults={"_format": "html"})
     */
    public function indexMenuAction()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Its routing.yml contains this

```
myproject_app_erp.myproject_admin.controller:
    resource: erp
    type: myproject_admin
```

and its sevice.yml contains this

```
services:
#    erp.example:
#        class: MyprojectAppErpBundle\Example
#        arguments: ["@service_id", "plain_value", "%parameter%"]
parameters:
    myproject_app_erp.routing_controllers:
        home: 'MyProject\App\ErpBundle\Controller\Admin\HomeController'
```

And, inside mainfolder/app/config/routing.yml I have this section:

```
myproject_app_erp:
    resource: '@MyprojectAppErpBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
```

In theory this should run the `HomeController` I need, which, in turn would work with the service I described, which will do something with the entities, but instead of that I get the following error:

> The parameter "myproject_app_erp.routing_controllers" must be defined
>   in erp (which is being imported from
>   "/var/www/mainfolder/vendor/myproject/sing/src/Myproject/App/ErpBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml").

I have tried to copy the `parameters` section from the service.yml into the routing.yml to have that section there, which was missed by the error message, but the error message remained. I have been trying to solve this since yesterday with a lot of approaches and I have the impression that I have more difficulties in setting up the working environment than with writing the code. I have read about service creation at the Symfony docs, this is why I have been able to reach as far as I reached, but I do not know how to solve this problem. I think I need to check how autoload works, since it seems that `/home` routes are controlled there, but I do not know whether I am right and how to reach that. My question is: what should I check, where and how to be able to solve this problem.

EDIT:

I have managed to avoid the error described above by implementing DependencyInjection, but creating a folder with the name of DependencyInjection into the `ErpBundle` and implementing the following two classes:

Configuration.php

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\App\ErpBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('myproject_app_erp');
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

MyprojectAppErpExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\App\ErpBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */

class MyprojectAppErpExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

While the page loads now, it still uses another bundle's `HomeController` than the one inside `ErpBundle`.

Comment: Autoloading has nothing to do with routing.  All I can suggest is make sure you are looking at the 2.8 docs since later version of Symfony have quite a few changes.  And no, don't try to define parameters in a routing file.  Consider following the intro docs and creating a brand new project just to get a basic understanding of how things work.  This whole thing about having a routing_controllers parameter is a bit bizarre.

Comment: @Cerad that's what the error message is asking. I have been looking at the right documentation, off course.

Comment: You might be surprised at how many people look at the wrong version of docs when inheriting ancient legacy code.  app/console debug:router might help figuring out what your routing is doing.  Maybe show the code that is using the parameter called myproject_app_erp.routing_controllers.  Maybe there is some kind of custom routing going on as this sort of parameter is definitely not normal for Symfony.  And while I assume it just typos in editing after copying your question, you do have a number of namespace inconsistencies including Myproject vs MyProject and Admin in your controller.

Comment: @Cerad they are most probably typos. I have triple-checked the pathes. I know there are many, who read the wrong documentation, occasionally I fall for it myself as well, but when I ask a question here, I try to make sure no such banalities are involved into the question. Since you stated that this is not normal in Symfony, which is probably accurate, I do not see the point of creating a new project, following Symfony's normal practices, since they are not applicable for my problem. The code you are asking for is the HomeController in the question.

Comment: @Cerad and the HomeController in the question does not run, instead another HomeController is running, which is the default HomeController. As you can see from my edits, I have managed to make progress by implementing DependencyInjection for ErpBundle, so the initial error has gone away, but unfortunately I am seeing the behavior that the default HomeController is executed instead of the one I need. There are other bundles which have their own HomeController (this is how I found out that I need to do DependencyInjection) and their HomeController is somehow executed instead of the default.

Comment: @Cerad so I am looking at those bundles and the general configuration to find out why their HomeController is correctly executed instead of the default.

Comment: Okay.  Don't think I'm going to be much help here.  Too many moving parts.  I will say that your posted routing.yml file needs help.  Kind of guessing it's not even being loaded as I am sure it would generate errors. https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing/external_resources.html

Comment: @Cerad you have already helped a bit, I thank you for that. Anyway, if I find out the issue, I will try to explain the solution in general terms. As about the routing.yml, I am sure it is executed, as the error message in the initial question was searching for settings in that file. It is executed, but for some reason, its settings have a lower priority than the default settings.

Comment: Hmmm.  Take a look at the app_annotations section in the link I gave you.  resource: erp and type: myproject_admin are not going to do anything for you.  They certainly won't load the annotated routes in your controller.

Comment: @Cerad there are similar settings in the routing.yml of other bundles and they work. From the very scarce information I've got, the other guy explained that the resource's value should be irrelevant, because the route loader does not use it. Is this meaning that the route loader is very specific in this project?

Comment: Yep.  A custom route loader is the only explanation I can think of that fits what you posted.  Pure speculation on my part but maybe look for classes that implement Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface

Comment: @Cerad thank you! I will look into them.

Comment: @Cerad it turns out that there is a custom routing-specific logic in the project and I had to do some database changes, following a project-specific convention previously unkown to me. The details are so specific, that I cannot share them here without violating the business secrets related to the project, so I know what the answer is, but cannot share this with the community. Should I remove this question?

Comment: The important thing is that I was finally right!  I would not delete the question as I think it was an interesting debug session.  Just copy your last comment into a short answer.  Might help someone else having legacy app fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a custom routing-specific logic in the project and I had to do some database changes, following a project-specific convention previously unkown to me. The details are so specific, that I cannot share them here without violating the business secrets related to the project, so I know what the answer is, but cannot share this with the community.